# How to Save all Responses to a file with loop count more that one?

Tags: jmeter

[image]

This is a part of my test plan, and the loop count is 2.However only one set of responses generated
even i select "Add timestamp"

so, how to save data base on loop count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have separate files with the responses for each thread (virtual user) and Thread Group iteration you can use

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function
- `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) as prefix or postfix for the filename

So given the following configuration:

[image]

Here is the textual representation just in case:

```
user-${__threadNum}-loop-${__jm__Thread Group__idx}-response.txt
```

You will have the following files:

```
user-1-loop-0-response.txt
user-1-loop-1-response.txt
user-2-loop-0-response.txt
user-2-loop-1-response.txt
```

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)